# Deploying Node.js bot from local computer to Azure framework

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, cmd

Trying to deploy a bot written in JavaScript and Node.js on Azure through the command prompt.

Command prompt will not respond to this:

```
az account set --subscription "azure subscription"
```

and will respond to this:

```
az bot prepare-deploy --code-dir "." --lang JavaScript
```

with this output:

> ```
> Command group 'bot' is in preview. It may be changed/removed in a future release.
> web.config found in .
> Please delete this web.config before calling "az bot prepare-deploy"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This Cli command :

```
az bot prepare-deploy --code-dir "." --lang JavaScript
```

will fetch a web.config which is needed for Node.js apps to work with IIS on Azure App Services. Make sure web.config is saved to the root of your bot.
So once you run it at the root of your bot project, a web.config file will be fetched,and if you run this command again,it will warn you that a web.config found in your project conflicts the prepare-deploy action. That is the reason why you see this out put. 
If you want to deploy your code to bot, pls use this command :

```
az bot publish -n "your bot name" -g "resource group name"
```

Or follow [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#2-deploy-code-to-azure) to deploy.
These two ways all works for me : 
[image]

Btw, pls note that if there is no reply after cli command execution, generally , that means your command has been executed successfully . 
Pls mark me if my suggestions are helpful :) 
Hope you have a nice day!